# Extra Unwanted Data Written in File While Uploading with Apache Httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to upload a database dump file using Apache Httpclient library and below code:

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("file",new FileBody(new File(fileDirectory))).build();
HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url + "/" + fileName);
request.setEntity(entity);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+authentication);
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

This is the extra unwanted data that is written in my file:

```
---NjPddruz8ocyxDtNnXaX1eigSH6W-gGgXD1O
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="wordpress.sql"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

--
-- Generated by java-mysql-exporter
-- Date: 14-11-2020 15:18:38
--

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

--
-- start  table dump : wp_commentmeta
--
```

Is there anyway that I could avoid these lines being written in my original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the format of multipart data.  multipart data is designed for including multiple different data objects in a single request (hence the separators and headers).  if you just want to upload a single file, you don't need to use multipart formatted data.  you could just upload using a FileEntity instead.